# Rotating Image with AffineTransform Produces Visually Correct Pixels, but getRGB Doesn't Match

Tags: java, image

I'm attempting to rotate an image 180 using AffineTransform. My "out.jpg" visually appears rotated, however when I attempt to programatically verify that the output image has been rotated , the code disagrees. Here's my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage origImage = ImageIO.read(new File("input.jpg"));
    
    AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform();
    int centerX = origImage.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = origImage.getHeight() / 2;
    // Rotate 180 degrees
    af.quadrantRotate(2, centerX, centerY);

    AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(af, null);
    BufferedImage destImage =
        new BufferedImage(origImage.getWidth(), origImage.getHeight(), origImage.getType());
    affineTransformOp.filter(origImage, destImage);

    // Verify that destImage has indeed been rotated by point checking a random pixel.
    int origX = 90;
    int origY = 32;
    // Where we expect this pixel to have been translated to.
    int expX = destImage.getWidth()-origX;
    int expY = destImage.getHeight()-origY;

    // Always prints false. Why????
    System.out.println("Pixels are equal: " +
      origImage.getRGB(origX, origY) == destImage.getRGB(expX, expY));

    ImageIO.write(destImage, "jpg", new File("out.jpg"));

}
```

What am I doing wrong with either my rotation or the programatic check?

I've verified in the documentation:

- getRGB() returns an int, there's no need to use .equals()
- BufferedImage indexes from (0,0) in the upper left corner
- AffineTransform.quadrantRotate() with an anchor, translates back to (0,0) once it completes the rotation
- AffineTransform.quadrantRotate() goes clockwise (although this shouldn't matter for 180 rotation)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong pixel.

Assume your image is `1x1` pixel in size. You're originally looking at pixel `(0, 0)`. Then with your code, in the destination image, you're looking at pixel `(width - 0, height - 1)`, which turns out to be pixel `(1, 1)`. When clearly you still need to be looking at `(0, 0)` as the image doesn't have a pixel at `(1, 1)`.

In your case, your transformed coordinate isn't outside your image, but it points to the wrong pixel.

To fix your code, change the lines that calculate your `expX` and `expY` values, and subtract 1 from each:

```
int expX = destImage.getWidth() - origX - 1;
int expY = destImage.getHeight() - origY - 1;
```

That returns the correct pixel values when I run your code (on my own image, as you haven't provided the image that you used).

There is another issue in the code that will only surface with an odd-numbered width or height: you're using integer arithmetic to determine the center of rotation, which rounds down when it shouldn't. Change the lines that determine the center to (to use floating-point numbers, so that you can get a fractional number as a result) :

```
double centerX = origImage.getWidth() / 2.0;
double centerY = origImage.getHeight() / 2.0;
```

Comment: There were two related problems, one of which was an off-by-one error, hence marking this solution as the answer. Additionally, I was rotating a JPEG image, which is lossy, so the pixel values were not exactly the same. When I updated my check to see if the Red, Green, Blue values were +/- 5 of the expected value, I got the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code using a png image of mine.  Here are my test results.  Image type 6 is TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR from the [BufferedImage source code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/image/BufferedImage-source.html).

```
Image size: 416 x 199
Image type: 6
Origin pixel: 90,32
Destination pixel: 326,167
Pixel values: ffeeeeee ffffffff
Pixels are equal: false
```

Here's the image.

[image]

Here's the rotated image.

[image: Rotated image]

I'm not sure why the colors are different.  I can't visually distinguish the difference between an `eeeeee` pixel and an `ffffff` pixel.

Edited to add: I did a little more research and found this bit of documentation for the `Image` `getRGB` method.

> Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model(TYPE_INT_ARGB)
> and default sRGB colorspace. Color conversion takes place if this
> default model does not match the image ColorModel.

So, it appears that the `getRGB` method itself could be causing the color conversion.

Here's the code I ran.

```
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class RotateImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Pictures"
                + "\\Saved Pictures\\CustomJTextField.png";
        BufferedImage origImage = ImageIO.read(new File(input));

        AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform();
        int centerX = origImage.getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = origImage.getHeight() / 2;
        // Rotate 180 degrees
        af.quadrantRotate(2, centerX, centerY);

        AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(
                af, null);
        System.out.println("Image size: " + origImage.getWidth() +
                " x " + origImage.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Image type: " + origImage.getType());
        BufferedImage destImage = new BufferedImage(
                origImage.getWidth(), origImage.getHeight(),
                origImage.getType());
        affineTransformOp.filter(origImage, destImage);

        // Verify that destImage has indeed been rotated by point
        // checking a random
        // pixel.
        int origX = 90;
        int origY = 32;
        // Where we expect this pixel to have been translated to.
        int expX = destImage.getWidth() - origX;
        int expY = destImage.getHeight() - origY;

        System.out.println("Origin pixel: " + origX + "," + origY);
        System.out.println("Destination pixel: " + expX + "," + expY);

        int origPixel = origImage.getRGB(origX, origY);
        int expPixel = destImage.getRGB(expX, expY);
        System.out.println("Pixel values: " +
                Integer.toHexString(origPixel) + " " +
                Integer.toHexString(expPixel));

        // Always prints false. Why????
        System.out.println("Pixels are equal: " +
                (origPixel == expPixel));

        String output = "C:\\Eclipse\\Eclipse-2020-workspace"
                + "\\com.ggl.testing2\\resources\\output.png";
        ImageIO.write(destImage, "png", new File(output));
    }

}
```

Edited to add: I wrote my own transform to see whether or not it was the transform changing the color or the `getRGB` method changing the color.

Here are the test results from my own transform.

```
Image size: 416 x 199
Image type: 6
Origin pixel: 90,32
Destination pixel: 326,167
Pixel values: ffeeeeee ffeeeeee
Pixels are equal: true
```

I created an int array of pixels from the original image and wrote those pixels to the rotated image.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class RotateImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Pictures"
                + "\\Saved Pictures\\CustomJTextField.png";
        BufferedImage origImage = ImageIO.read(new File(input));

        System.out.println("Image size: " + origImage.getWidth() +
                " x " + origImage.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Image type: " + origImage.getType());
        int[] pixels = getPixels(origImage);

        BufferedImage destImage = new BufferedImage(
                origImage.getWidth(), origImage.getHeight(),
                origImage.getType());
        destImage = putPixels(destImage, pixels);

        // Verify that destImage has indeed been rotated by point
        // checking a random
        // pixel.
        int origX = 90;
        int origY = 32;
        // Where we expect this pixel to have been translated to.
        int expX = destImage.getWidth() - origX;
        int expY = destImage.getHeight() - origY;

        System.out.println("Origin pixel: " + origX + "," + origY);
        System.out.println("Destination pixel: " + expX + "," + expY);

        int origPixel = origImage.getRGB(origX, origY);
        int expPixel = destImage.getRGB(expX, expY);
        System.out.println("Pixel values: " +
                Integer.toHexString(origPixel) + " " +
                Integer.toHexString(expPixel));
        System.out.println("Pixels are equal: " +
                (origPixel == expPixel));

        String output = "C:\\Eclipse\\Eclipse-2020-workspace"
                + "\\com.ggl.testing2\\resources\\output.png";
        ImageIO.write(destImage, "png", new File(output));
    }

    private static int[] getPixels(BufferedImage image) {
        int length = image.getWidth() * image.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[length];
        int index = 0;

        for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
                pixels[index++] = image.getRGB(w, h);
            }
        }

        return pixels;
    }

    private static BufferedImage putPixels(BufferedImage image,
            int[] pixels) {
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = pixels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int h = index / image.getWidth();
            int w = index % image.getWidth();
            image.setRGB(w, h, pixels[i]);
            index++;
        }

        return image;
    }

}
```